# Keyboard replacing W, H, C, X, and Y with random Unicode characters. Possible causes and solutions?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

I was on the FurAffinity forums today, and came across this thread in the Technology Talk section.

The user making this thread is currently experiencing this issue:

[image]

In text, in case you can't load the image:

> m□ dis□ord □as gone all □eird and m□ t□it□□.
> and no□ it's doing t□is t□ing □□ere it repla□es random letters □it□ bo□es.
> it sa□s m□ SVG □ode□ is □orrupted. □□at does t□at mean?

From what I can tell, it seems that certain characters are being randomly swapped with unicode characters.

Based on missing characters, they are saying:

> my discord has gone all weird and my twitch.
> and now it's doing this thing where it replaces random letters with boxes.
> it says my SVG codex is corrupted. what does that mean?

While I am unsure of the solution they found (they did eventually find one, and failed to share it), I couldnt find any threads or topics on a similar issue to try and help them.

Any help finding the cause of this issue, as well as a solution for those in the future would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not fully understond: Does this happen on everyone's computer, or just yours? Does this problem gone suddenly or it is still there?

Comment: An observation: Only these five characters are affected: `{'c', 'h', 'w', 'x', 'y'}`.

Comment: This happened on this one persons computer. The person who originally posted the thread found a solution and failed to post it

Answer (score 0):

With a script seems that only these five characters are affected: `{'c', 'h', 'w', 'x', 'y'}`.

Script:

```python
s1 = """m□ dis□ord □as gone all □eird and m□ t□it□□. and no□ it's doing t□is t□ing □□ere it repla□es random letters □it□ bo□es. it sa□s m□ SVG □ode□ is □orrupted. □□at does t□at mean?"""
s2 = """my discord has gone all weird and my twitch. and now it's doing this thing where it replaces random letters with boxes. it says my SVG codex is corrupted. what does that mean?"""
# len(s1) == len(s2) == 175
l = [ s2[i] for i in range(175)
     if s1[i] != s2[i] ]
set(l)
```

Since it only happens on an individual computer, I guess those `□`s are not unicode characters - since the possibility of webpage text get modified is very tiny - just that the font on that computer lacks these characters. Same thing will happen by browsering a website containing CJK characters from a computer without CJK fonts - the characters not included in the font will be printed as `□`.